# React formik - how to run a function after setValues

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, formik

What is the convention on how to run a function after the formik setValues function was run.

```
setValues((prev) => ({
  ...prev,
  companyName: value.get('name') || prev.companyName,
  companyNumber: value.get('id') || prev.companyNumber,
}))
```

In this function I should check if the `companyName` has changed, and if it has changed I should run another `async` function. I know that in react `setState` you can pass a callback as a param and then you know it will run after `setState` has finished. How can I do something like this with formik?

Answer (score 0):

Try useEffect and add formik values into depedndecies:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // do something
  }, [formik.values.companyName]);
```

Comment: Do you know how can I avoid running this ```useEffect``` on the first render?

Comment: Are you using <Formik /> or useFormik? Plese,  show you formik code

Comment: Depends what you want to do, you can use `if` conditoin in `useEffect`